# email links not working - date.timezone function

Tags: civimail, settings, timezone

I have used my CiviCRM email for many years. Today I had the following error message when I sent an email with links in it clicking through to an event on an external site. I have resolved the problem temporarily by not tracking click-throughs, but what could be causing this?

> It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second Jon G's answer with this reference -- Jon actually helped on [a similar issue I had](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/3569/105).  The issue was indeed that the php.ini did not specify the time zone.  The answer on this question fixed it for me: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3589/105

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of this more helpful one.

Comment: Great thank you