# Why does CiviMail 'track click through' redirect to incorrect URLs?

Tags: civimail

I seem to be having a problem that a number of people are running into that I'm hoping we can solve. When I sent out emails using the "track click through" enabled, I end up with URLs that direct to white screens.

What should direct to http://www.mysite.com/contribute/

instead directs to this url, which gives a white screen.

http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=191&qid=5085

We're running
Wordpress 4.3.1
CiviCRM 4.6.6

thoughts? suggestions? Would it help to post the actual site urls? Needless to say as this is a fundraising email, I've got a development director in the other room melting down over this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A development director with melt down... I know the feeling, and you have my sympathy! Hopefully someone could give you a tip during the weekend:-)

Comment: I don't use WP much but demo shows the link you should be putting in should be like http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

Comment: I assume you are using some WP redirect that is setting /contribute to 'something else'. Can you check what you have entered there and report back.

Comment: -petednz No, the link is right. Works just fine on the site. And no WP redirect (It's just CiviCRM contribution in a WP page). The "track click through" just gives that weird link to the white screen of death and I can't seem to figure it out. Also of note, if I turn off the "track click throughs" in an email I send out, the links work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Devin, your description is eerily similar to a problem I had on our Drupal site.  Without track click through, things were fine.  Once those were enabled, no dice.

For our situation ([CiviMail - when Track Click Throughs is enabled, links result in a white screen with warnings](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/3569/105)), it turns out it was due to a PHP setting issue.  [Jon G's answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3595/105) explains the why.  [Richard's answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3589/105) explains how we fixed it.

Hope this helps!