# Mailings: Error 500 with Click Through Tracking

Tags: civimail, drupal, bootstrap, tracked-links

I get an error with tracked urls in mailings. When the user clicks the link inside the mail, he gets a page telling him "error 500".

If error reporting is on in php, I get following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_add_http_header() in /home/www/<...>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Drupal.php on line 790
```

The URL called is

```
http://<mydomain>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=221&qid=1851
```

As workaround, I could solve the problem adding a call to loadBootStrap():

```
  public function setHttpHeader($name, $value) {
    self::loadBootStrap([], false);
    drupal_add_http_header($name, $value);
  }
```

But I belive this a very dirty thing to do! :-/

With this fix, all things works fine with the same url from above!

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.Beta3 and Drupal core 7.41.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: When the user clicks on the link, what does the resulting web address look like? Might anything from this question help - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/3569/105 ?

Comment: I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.Beta3 and Drupal core 7.41.


URLs are just right, but like mentioned in the post, I get this "undefinend function error"!


The error from your link something different.

Comment: Please update your question to provide an example URL in reply to Allen's question above?

Comment: If edited the question!

Comment: Thank you @Tiggr for the additional info.  Did you install 4.7beta3 fresh or was it an upgrade from a prior version? If an upgrade, what version did you upgrade from?

Comment: My 4.7beta3 is an upgrade from 4.6.10