# CiviMail Tracked Click Throughs not Redirecting

Tags: civimail, drupal, 4.7, tracked-links

I am using CiviCRM with Drupal 7 (latest version). After upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7, the Track Click Through links in my mailings have stopped redirecting. They just go to the custom CiviCRM URL's, but don't redirect, leaving simply a white page. Everything worked fine before the upgrade.

As instructed in [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/civimail-when-track-click-throughs-is-enabled-links-result-in-a-white-screen), I have added this code to the .htaccess file in the appropriate block area:

`php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"`

I also tried using the ini_set command for civicm.setting.php mentioned in the same post.

Help please!

Comment: Per that post, did you make sure that the php_value line is surrounded by the <IfModule mod_php5.c> if you didn't have it already?

Comment: Yes, I did it exactly as in that post.

Comment: Looks like this: `# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
  php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
</IfModule>`

Comment: Roger that.  Just checking.

Comment: Thanks. Could this be a permissions issue? Most of the CiviCRM module files have 664 and the folder have 775.

Comment: Thanks Allen for your you help. Does anybody else have any other ideas for things I could try or look for? This is pretty important to our organization. Thanks.

Comment: Could this have something to do with this bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17953

Comment: I think it might be.  Can you turn on debugging briefly to test if that specifies any error (maybe the 500 error the Jira issue mentions)?

Comment: To clarify, if you send a mailing without Track Click Through, do the links work?

Comment: The links work fine when the tracking is turned off, thank goodness. I am not sure how to turn on debugging or what to look for when I do. Just a little bit of guidance on that would be helpful. Thanks Allen.

Comment: Sure thing - from the main menu, Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling. You will want to enable debugging and backtrace.  Then click a tracked link from your mailing and see if it produces any more information.

Comment: Thanks Allen. I enabled all three options under the Debugging and Error Handling settings. I clicked a couple of links from an email. And it was exactly the same, no error on the web page - just blank. Also, there were not errors generated to the Drupal log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in CiviCRM 4.7.1, and it's been fixed in 4.7.2 - which hasn't been released as of this writing.  However, if you're comfortable applying the patch, the fix has been released.  See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17953 for details.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I don't really know how to do a patch (I'm not a real doctor. I just play one online), so I will wait for 4.7.2 unless someone is able to spell it out for me how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server's php.ini file you could try adding the directive there:

`date.timezone="America/New_York"`

With our host Media Temple, you can include additional directives for the php.ini from within the server UI rather than the command line (in our domain's PHP settings).

Comment: No such access. :-(